# Getting exception : com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: The provided authentication header is invalid

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The code was working from last 6 months and processing the data as well.

But we started observing this exception with the same code. Now as well we are able to connect and process the data. We want to understand more about this exception? what may be the root cause of these exceptions.
We are using - `google-cloud-storage-1.93.0.jar` and `google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar`.

```
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: The provided authentication header is invalid.
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:229)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.list(HttpStorageRpc.java:370)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$8.call(StorageImpl.java:374)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$8.call(StorageImpl.java:371)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBlobs(StorageImpl.java:370)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:326)
```

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The provided authentication header is invalid.",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "The provided authentication header is invalid."
}
```

We have tried to call the storage API by removing some headers from the json file. But it is throwing exceptions at client side.

Comment: Please let me know if the information below was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error “message": `The provided authentication header is invalid` - it's mostly that the request failed because it contained an invalid header value. The value could be a parameter value, a header value, or a property value.

The most common root cause for this issue is:

1. If you use any resumable uploads, You may see the 400 error message when your current resumable upload is no longer active.  For that you need to start a new resumable upload as stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#400_bad_request)

> your current resumable upload is no longer active, and you must start a new resumable upload.

2. Also check the current client version that is reaching the GCS API. Sometimes you may face this issue as the client version is not up to date. This needs to be updated.

Also it seems like a bug. Feel free to either raise a [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) or contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for the same issue .